# Optimize drawRect to avoid crashing app

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext

I have a puzzle game that I would like to add a 500 piece option to. I am currently using `drawRect` to draw the shape of the piece on. I pre calculate the shape of the pieces and use the path to clip the image like so:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, self.path);

    self.boundingBox = CGContextGetPathBoundingBox(ctx);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    [self.delegate.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

This will crash the app and send the Memory through the roof. I comment out the `drawRect` and the views are added successfully and very fast. This works with 100 pieces, but anything higher it crashes the app. If I comment out all of the code in `drawRect` I still get the crash.

**Note I don't get a crash, I get `Process finished with exit code 0`**

How can I improve the performance here?

Comment: Is `self.path` a pointer to a `UIBezierPath` or is it a `CGPathRef`?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your program still crashes if you comment out all this code?

Comment: @stevekohls it is a CGMutablePathRef, @Chuck it crashes if I comment the code inside the `drawRect`. If I comment out the `drawRect` entirely it doesn't crash.

Comment: What happens if you comment out only the `drawAtPoint` call? How large is your image?

Comment: It still crashes. The image is 800px by 600px

Comment: Show us the backtrace.

Comment: There is no backtrace that I can find. It just closes with `Process finished with exit code 0`